# In dialogflow, need to capture real time logs of chatbots conversations

Tags: dialogflow-es

In dialogflow, interact with users using chatbots conversations. Need to logs all these chatbots conversations logs in real time in database so that perform some actions on these at our end.  In fulfilment, cannot do this due to timeout issue i.e. 5 seconds. Please help to implement this in dialogflow.